# Load more functionality from random generated data in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, rest, web-services

I'm developing web service for my Android application. I have a lot of data in MySQL table. My service fetching this data randomly using RAND() function. I get a lot of records. So, I need to add load more functionality. But my data is constantly changing.

I've tried adding a limit but same data can come.

```
SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY RAND();
```

I want to come the data in sectional.

Can you give me an idea or method? Thanks.

Comment: Since you are ordering randomly, you can't fetch with a limit/offset.

Comment: What is the reason for the random ordering?

Comment: There is discover section of my app. Items needs to come differently not ordered.

Comment: `ORDER BY RAND()` is a fantastic way to utterly obliterate the performance of any query, and even entire servers! https://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/

Comment: Thank you so much but I need the data randomly. I guess I'il change the algorithm. Maybe I can do it locally.

Comment: I'll post a possible answer for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to handle this would be by excluding the currently loaded items from the second query, for example:

```sql
SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10;
```

Then, when making the second query you can exclude the items you've already loaded:

```sql
SELECT * FROM news WHERE `id` NOT IN(<loaded ids>) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10;
```

This will ensure that there are no duplicates loaded.

Comment: Neat. Large `IN()` clauses are also huge performance sinkholes, so now we've got a multiplying factor in how fast your performance will tank.

Comment: I'll try this. I'll confirm if it works. Thanks again.

Comment: Apperantly I'm going to have performance issues. It's supposed to be like this at first. Then I will get the data according to the frequency of reading.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is built to serve ordered data optimized by index and `ORDER BY RAND()` blows both of these to bits. If you don't want to go completely into the complexity of the link I sent, a simpler solution would be something like:

1. `SELECT id FROM news;`
2. `$_SESSION['news_shuffle'] = array_shuffle($results_from_previous);` shuffle happens *once* per user, and PHP is better at randomizing things than MySQL.
3. `$_SESSION['news_shuffle_offset'] = 0;` and increment it each time you pick an article.
4. `$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM news WHERE id = ?');`
5. `$stmt->execute([$_SESSION['news_shuffle'][$_SESSION['news_shuffle_offset']]);`

It's not the most elegant solution, but it also won't tip over your server once you have more than a handful of users/articles.